# I want to dispaly all product with their (name,description,price,image) using php

Tags: php

I need help, I am new to in PHP, I want to display all product with their name, description, price, image and i also want them to be display in Div/grid using php.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please update your question with the code you have tried and didn't work, errors related to it. Review [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: i am new and i don't have any code yet

Answer (score 0):

Create a database with tables.
Then store your product details
Then you can use PHP and SQL to fetch all the information and display in div.
If you don't have database skills, try learn it before you move on.
If you're extremely new to PHP, I'll suggest you start to learn from the basics like variable, method, loops, arrays, connect to database, etc  so that you can provide some code and we can help you easily.

Babies can't drive cars.